# Using a variable inside the mkdir function

Tags: c

When I write it this way, it creates a file named filename, but I want the user to create what user has entered

```
char filename[255];
printf("Enter your file name: ");
scanf("%s",filename);
mkdir("C:\\Users\\DAVUTBOZTAŞ\\Desktop\\filename",0777);
```

---

Comment: Then pass `filename` instead of the hardcoded string. You might want to concatenate it with the root directory though. Are you asking how to concatenate?

Comment: `snprintf` to construct the name.

Comment: With that said, be *very* careful when using user-input to construct paths. What happens if the user adds a few `..` in the input?

Comment: Try `sprintf/snprintf`: `char filename[255]; printf("Enter your file name: "); scanf("%s", filename); char path[1024]; sprintf(path,"C:\\Users\\DAVUTBOZTAŞ\\Desktop\\%s", filename); mkdir(path, 0777);`

Comment: @EugeneSh.: More fun way: `char filename[255+34] = "C:\\Users\\DAVUTBOZTAŞ\\Desktop\\"; … scanf("%s", filename + strlen(filename)); mkdir(filename, 0777);`.

Comment: Or simply build the filename by using strcpy()/strcat() into a new buffer. Watch for overflow.

Comment: @PaulLynch `snprintf()` is much easier than lots of strcats

Comment: Just in general, variables are not expanded inside strings. If you want to substitute a variable into a string, use string functions or formatting.

Comment: `mkdir` conforms to `POSIX.1-2001` and `POSIX.1-2008`. If your system does support `POSIX.1-2008` then you could also use the `mkdirat` function (see https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/mkdir.2.html), which would allow you to specify a base directory, which in your case would be `"C:\\Users\\DAVUTBOZTAŞ\\Desktop\\"` and a `pathname`, which would be that the user has entered (with all the checks).

Comment: @Barmar Not sure 1 call each is "lots." snprintf() offers destination size checking (assuming it's specified right) but it's a whole lot of code to suck in for just one %s format specifier. Potato/potahto.

Comment: @PaulLynch I was speaking in general. In this case it's just two calls, but I still consider it more readable to use snprintf. And stdio is usually already being used, so you're not really sucking in anything extra.

Comment: http://idownvotedbecau.se/noattempt/

Answer (score 1):

Your `mkdir()` function just hast a constant string (`const char*`) as argument, which is evaluated at compile time and has nothing to do with your userinput.
You could ask the user to input the full (absolue) path you want to create and then put this as argument like the following code:

```
char filename[255];
printf("Enter your file name (absolue path): ");
scanf("%s",filename);
mkdir(filename, 0777);
```

If you want the user to not have to write the whole path with like "C:\Users\"..., you can just have a sub path pre defined and concatenate both strings after the users input:

```
char filename[255];
char fullPath[255];

printf("Enter your file name: ");
scanf("%s", filename);
sprintf(fullPath, "C:\\Users\\DAVUTBOZTAŞ\\Desktop\\%s", filename);
mkdir(fullPath, 0777);
```

A third option, similar to the second, would be to get the users profile so your program works even when someone else runs it:

```
char filename[255];
char fullPath[255];

printf("Enter your file name: ");
scanf("%s", filename);
sprintf(fullPath, "%s\\Desktop\\%s", getenv("USERPROFILE"), filename);
mkdir(fullPath, 0777);
```

The `getenv()` function returns a string containing the current profile, in your case `"C:\\Users\\DAVUTBOZTAŞ"`.

---

**Edit:**

As "@Eric Postpischil" commented on this post, you should rather use `FILENAME_MAX`, which is defined in `<stdio.h>`, for creating your `char` arrays. `FILENAME_MAX` is an integer value which should be used to create strings which shall contain file paths. In my case `FILENAME_MAX` evaluates to `260`.

You should also use other functions to not overflow your strings.
The function `fgets()` works better in our case. It expects a `char*`, its size and a `FILE*`, for which you use `stdin`, the standard input from your console, defined in the header `<stdio.h>`. You can see its usage in the following snippet.
Further you should use `snprintf()` instead of just `sprintf()` for the same reason.

```
char filename[FILENAME_MAX];
char fullPath[FILENAME_MAX];

printf("Enter your file name: ");
fgets(filename, FILENAME_MAX, stdin);
snprintf(fullPath, FILENAME_MAX, "%s\\Desktop\\%s", getenv("USERPROFILE"), filename);
    
mkdir(fullPath, 0777);
```

Comment: Programs should generally use `FILENAME_MAX`, defined in `<stdio.h>`, for the size of an array to contain a file name, rather than `255`, and should include guards against overflowing the array.